# How to convince TypeScript by function that object is defined

Tags: typescript

Code:

```
public get scaleString(): string {
  const previewScale = !ObjectHelper.isNullOrUndefined(this.previewWidth) && !ObjectHelper.isNullOrUndefined(this.realWidth)
    // Object is possibly 'undefined'
    ? this.previewWidth / this.realWidth
    : 1;

  const scaleInPercent = previewScale * this.scale * 100;

  return `${scaleInPercent.toFixed(2)}%`;
}
```

ObjectHelper method:

```
public static isNullOrUndefined(v: object | string | boolean | number | null | undefined): boolean {
  return v === undefined || v === null;
}
```

What I get is a visual studio code / TypeScript error:

- Object is possibly 'undefined'

[image]

One way would be to add if statements:

```
const previewScale = this.previewWidth !== undefined && this.previewWidth !== null && this.realWidth !== undefined && this.realWidth !== null
    ? this.previewWidth / this.realWidth
    : 1;
```

Is it possible to convince TypeScript that the upper function ObjectHelper.IsNullOrUndefined checked that already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make `isNullOrUndefined` a type guard:

```
  public static isNullOrUndefined(v: object | string | boolean | number | null | undefined): v is null | undefined {
    return v === undefined || v === null;
  }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Might I just suggest you can use  `== null` as a replacement for the function `x == null` will be true if x is `null` or `undefined`. It's short, idiomatic to JS  and TS understands it:

```
  public get scaleString(): string {
    const previewScale = this.previewWidth != null && this.realWidth != null
      // Object is possibly 'undefined'
      ? this.previewWidth / this.realWidth
      : 1;

    const scaleInPercent = previewScale * this.scale * 100;

    return `${scaleInPercent.toFixed(2)}%`;
  }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAa0G8BQ1oAcBOBTAbgSywHcB1PAEwBcALAfgC5oA7AVwFsAjLDAbhWmzAhSlWgxYcuvVBGCCsYtpwzQAvNAAMU9M3Yg8waAHMsFaDLkBlChjyNDACgCUDCNduHEfVMAD2jV+jY+EQWsiBYqtDUeBAAdJi4BCTk1NAAhGosICDQAGS5UVQxsQJCKVTpmczZXqjQAPT10ADy7ABWWMCmMeg+UHi6AJ7QAOTMjGRYAGa2WGQjtag0hcUJwckiDStxpcLUi9AMAIy8tb7+pubhAJKMAApcwFiMpmprSaFy0ABU27FXEV+R3UmiQtWwFGYGEY0AABgASBAA24PDBPF6xCg+ABieAAHnN7AAmRwAXwApLCtKSkKSgA)

Comment: we have a eslint rule   "eqeqeq": ["error","always"] so we can't use only two ==, or !=, but thanks for the info.

Comment: @broadband Following  lint rules unquestioningly is not always a good idea. That rule even allows an exception for `null` precisely because of this (https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/eqeqeq). I would recommend having a discussion with whoever enabled that rule about WHY they chose not to allow `x == null`.

Comment: We voted together for this rule, but have plans after release of the application, to change some things. Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You can define the `isNullOrUndefined` like this

```
class ObjectHelper {
    static isNullOrUndefined(input: any): input is null | undefined {
        return [null, undefined].includes(input)
    }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyBGArApsALgCWSADsgTtAN4BQ050EaYaAlsNLRAHICuIIs+AqgHYAmyAGa1eyfgApROVmgBc0MLwCeASgXTZjGL3YhoAH2isBw0eOJkK1-MjSt8vaAG1dHADTHTIsfwC6AHSioKyCEFK8MmiqVuQAviQJJKCQMACClrHQOLYAbrTIAO4A6rT8aAAWAPwKugC28ARZtmAgpeXVtawNTdYQwK3IXT2EALzQAIwA9ADMJFky8CD00ADmdpQDIMgAymj4oqsS6pT7h5bW1sAA9rxU2XkFhTtbyNDjAIQIKOhYuARBFh6Lh8QQ+cQSSpMAI5ZD5IrtSqqaAAMhR0C+SFQmGweHwgLYHBB3nMkihEACLTaZSRWUuFCmUzgWPQ2my1ygtCWymgAHITGDSby6fToFVoOSYY8ETSKtAmZKqYiKiL6QoJgBueai6A3O5oTaDACSvAACgRgMheAbxrD4c9XtAAFQSirQ-qDZ2TAAM3q1qugtnsjmgAAMACRED3bE3m-CW60BNDXABitAAHhCAEyqOIAUlDWusSTiQA)

---

#### Edit: Even better

you can define it using Extract as:

```
class ObjectHelper {
    static isNullOrUndefined<T>(input: T): input is Extract<T, null | undefined> {
        return input === null || input === undefined
    }
}
```

This way you'll be able to statically extract the `null` or `undefined` based on the input type

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyBGArApsALgCWSADsgTtAN4BQ050EaYaAlsNLRAHICuIIs+AqgHYAmyAGa1eyfgB4AKgD4AFKJys0ALmhSAlGsXLGMAKIAPNPjDppAGmi92IaAB9orAcNHiZxMhW-5kaVvi8jLxKaNAAvJHWtg6OOmGR4U4uImL8XuQAviTZJIKgYL7QwAD2vFSUJqIA5lxsHFx8gqnialT4NQ7RHF3OzW78ANx5qOBFpeVh7TV1tm1VvNVdNhzD+WPIxWUV04uNKQPzHYu9B2lro4WbExVlIACeAMoL1Uc1JCS0QtByCCjoWFwBAAdEx6pweGdxHJdrV8OCNBpPN40Pc8CVvrDZhwMtAAPR46AACwIm1oaAA5DAqDR6GAOPdoABrXglADuQTQRJo0C5m1ReD00DujJWIByHy+Pz+qEw2Dw+FBLFs+36aRhL1VrjSiORFAFyAxlWOcKa2vEuIJxNJjEp1OodGA9IezNZHN53LCfN5aLJMBFyTVFtynyEvyQssBCqV4K1LX4chFzxNutIKN9RqTLw+3itAD1oGABNait6DUKxAA3Ag5IA)